# Should I set null to big items After building JSTL classic Select tag

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, memory-leaks, jstl

I am writing a JSTL classic Html select tag. The tag has one BIG items (List) that used to build  tag. The below is my code:

```
public class MyBigSelectTag extends TagSupport {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected List<SelectItem> bigItems;

@Override
public void release() {

    // Release bigItems when the tag is releasing.
    this.bigItems = null;
}

@Override
public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
    JspWriter out = this.pageContext.getOut();
    try {
        out.write("<select>");
        for (SelectItem option : bigItems) {
            out.write("<option />");
        }
        out.write("</select>");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new JspTagException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } finally {
        // Do I have to set null to bigItems Here because it is too big?
        this.bigItems = null;
    }
    return super.doEndTag();
}

public void setBigItems(List<SelectItem> bigItems) {
    this.bigItems = bigItems;
}
}
```

My question is: **Do I have to set NULL into bigItems attributes in FINALLY block because the bigItems is TOO BIG**?  Note that I already set null to this attribute in 'release' function.

Anyone has any idea?  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to. The `release()` method will be called on your tag, and will set it to null.

And even if you didn't set it to null in the `release()` method, it would be garbage-collected at some point (when the tag is reused and another list replaces the current one).

Also, I doubt your list is so big. It's useful to have some numbers in mind. To be usable, a select box shouldn't have more than a few items, let's say 100, which is already a big number for a select box. Your items contain a value and a label: let's say they both have 50 characters, so 100 characters, so 200 bytes. Add some place for the references, the list, etc. and you should come to something like 300 bytes, multiplied by 100 items, so 30000 bytes, which means 30 KBs. This is far from being BIG. It's tiny.